# Laravel Collection Query, Where I am going wrong?

Tags: php, laravel

My tables looks like this

```
area_trip

|id|dispatch_id|trip_id|status|

equipment_trip

|equipment_id|trips_id|dispatch_id|

trips

|id|dispatch_id|status
```

I am trying to pass collection to my resource. Can someone check my query and tell me what I am doing wrong as following query returning all the data matches dispatch_id whether it matches equipment_id or not. Btw I am new to laravel.

```
return 
      Resources::collection(
        area_trip::where('dispatch_id', $request->dispatch_id)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->orWhere('status', 9)

        ->whereHas('equipment_trip', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('equipment_trip.equipment_id', '=', $request->equipment_id);
           })

            ->with(['equipment_trip', 'createdBy', 'updatedBy', 'area', 'trips'])
      ->orderBy('tripStartDate', 'ASC')
      ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
      ->get());
```

Here is the relationship set up in area_trip model

```
public function equipment_trip()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(equipment_trip::class, 'trip_id', 'trips_id');

}
```

Comment: how is the relationship setup in their models??

Comment: @ashish relationship added above

Comment: you probably want to check the query that is generated here and the placement of the `or`.

Comment: @lagbox how to check the query generated? also I tried to remove the or as you suggested and now I don't get any result

Comment: im still having difficulty to understand what should be the expected resulted here. can you be more precise. :)

Comment: @ashish I am sending a dispatch_id and a equipment_id so I want all the rows matching both. Currently I am getting all the results that matches only disptach_id

Answer (score 0):

I believe your whereHas sub query is incorrect also instead of where and orWhere use where in and you can define all statuses necessary, try this:

```
Resource::collection(area_trip::where('dispatch_id', $request>dispatch_id)
    ->whereIn('status', [1, 9])
    ->whereHas('equipment_trip', function($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->where('equipment_id', '=', $request->equipment_id);
    })
    ->with(['equipment_trip', 'createdBy', 'updatedBy', 'area', 'trips'])
    ->orderBy('tripStartDate', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
    ->get());
```